# Gitlab analytics legend

Tags: gitlab-ci

When i use gitlab analytics chart and hover over a bar, there is `full` with number. Intuitively I would guess it is the total time, but it does not match height of the bar. What does it mean?

[image: gitlab ci analytics bar chart]

Edit to add more context.
This happens when i use parallel build in gradle, if i don't use it, the value matches the height of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value appears to be the number of minutes in the pipeline(s) associated with that commit.

It's unclear to me whether this is intended to be shown or not. It's also unclear why the value you see doesn't seem to match the bar. On my self-hosted GitLab instance as well as on GitLab.com I don't see this popup in the CI/CD analytics, so I'm not able to reproduce the behavior in your screenshot. If you are using an older version of self-hosted GitLab, perhaps this was an issue that was previously fixed.

## Insights from source code

You can find the source code that describes this value in the GitLab repository, in [pipeline_charts.vue#L197-198](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/05208beab59955ba602445d233990fd4c6541d60/app/assets/javascripts/projects/pipelines/charts/components/pipeline_charts.vue#L197-198):

```js
    timesChartTransformedData() {
      return [
        {
          name: 'full',
          data: this.mergeLabelsAndValues(this.timesChartData.labels, this.timesChartData.values),
        },
      ];
    },
```

Digging deeper, `timesChartData.values` maps to `this.analytics.pipelineTimesValues` and `timesChartData.labels` maps to `this.analytics.pipelineTimesLabels`. These values are described in code as an array of integers and an array of strings representing the commit short SHAs -- as seen in [this mock data](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/05208beab59955ba602445d233990fd4c6541d60/spec/frontend/projects/pipelines/charts/mock_data.js#L204-267).

At runtime, this data is populated from the [GraphQL PipelineAnalytics](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/#pipelineanalytics) `pipelineTimesValues` and `pipelineTimesLabels` fields. The descriptions provided for these fields are not particularly helpful:

| Field Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pipelineTimesLabels | [String!] | Pipeline times labels. |
| pipelineTimesValues | [Int!] | Pipeline times. |

### Looking at data examples

You can use a [GraphQL query](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/#graphiql) to see this data. Using [gitlab-org/gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab) as an example, the following query:

```
{
  project(fullPath: "gitlab-org/gitlab") {
    fullPath
    pipelineAnalytics {
      pipelineTimesLabels
      pipelineTimesValues
    }
  }
}
```

Produces the following output (at time of writing):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "project": {
      "fullPath": "gitlab-org/gitlab",
      "pipelineAnalytics": {
        "pipelineTimesLabels": [
          "836b4ef6",
          "673ade85",
          "051de030",
          "d30d33de",
          "05208bea",
          "e72cb586",
          "556589fe",
          "89dec139",
          "95ee5946",
          "48c43849",
          "31858115",
          "ffd81a94",
          "b475ccde",
          "03d0dd43",
          "f4258d22",
          "4faeb29f",
          "68a4263e",
          "230bf3c2",
          "2ecfdfc1",
          "0fa4751d",
          "f1c7d634",
          "05208bea",
          "95ee5946",
          "8628de54",
          "89dec139",
          "31858115",
          "33b2fe92",
          "ffd81a94",
          "30f303fd",
          "403400be"
        ],
        "pipelineTimesValues": [
          0,
          6,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1,
          0,
          0,
          12,
          27,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I spot-check the commit `673ade85` (the second label) should line up to the times data point `6` (the second value). And `556589fe` (the seventh label) should map to the value `1` (the seventh value).

To the best of my ability, the data seen on these two commits seems to support the assertion that the value maps to the number of minutes in the pipeline(s):

Pipeline for `673ade85` lasted 6 minutes:

[image: commit 673ade85 pipelines]

Pipeline for `556589fe` lasted 1 minute:

[image: Commit 556589fe]

Comment: So i dug for a bit and it seems like it shows the duration of last pipeline on that commit. Because one commit can have more pipelines running. Which in my case ran sequentially. It is also visible that the bar consists of 2 smaller rectangles which each one of them is the pipeline duration.

Comment: @skorpilvaclav gotcha, so that might explain the difference in the bar height. With that understanding, if my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it :)